# update value state in array of objects

Tags: reactjs

State:

```
const [tiles, setTiles] = useState(tilesData)
```

Data inside state: (tilesData)

```
const defaultValueCard = {
   name: 'Bahamut',
   cardValues: { N: 0, E: 0, S: 0, W: 0 },
   image: 'URL'
}

export const tilesData =
   [
      { tileNumber: 1, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 2, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 3, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 4, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 5, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 6, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 7, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 8, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 9, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 10, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 11, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 12, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 13, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 14, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 15, card: defaultValueCard },
      { tileNumber: 16, card: defaultValueCard }
   ]
```

The **updateTile** function receives a tileIndex (numbered between 1-16) and a new card which contains the same data as the **defaultValueCard**.

*How can I inside this function update the state to replace the old card with a new one at the specific index?*

```
const updateTile = (tileIndex, card) => {
 /* take the tileIndex and update the current card with the parameter card */
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: No unfortunately. It's being solved using jQuery.

Comment: The accepted answer is vanilla js; they provided the links to the MDN in each option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
const [tiles, setTiles] = useState(tilesData);

const updateTile = (tileIndex, card) => {
 /* take the tileIndex and update the current card with the parameter card */
 const tilesCopy = [...tiles];
 const oldTileIndex = tilesCopy.findIndex(tile => tile.tileNumber === tileIndex);
 // a word of caution, oldTileIndex is undefined if tile with tileIndex DNE
 tilesCopy[oldTileIndex] = {tileNumber: tileIndex, card};
 setTiles(tilesCopy);
 
}
```